Equivalent definition of a PTNDTM?
$NP$ is the class of problems with a polynomial time non-deterministic turing machine which can determine whether an input is in a certain language or not. It can be seen as polynomial time deterministic verification, given a witness in a non-deterministic way.
$NL$ is the class of non-deterministic logarithmic space. Specifically, it is also deterministic verification of an input, given a non deterministic witness of logarithmic space (But does that mean the Verification algorithm itself must also use logarithmic space, or just the witness's size?).
The class of I came across has a similar definition to $NL$. It consists of
languages for which a deterministic polynomial time verifier and a single unique logarithmic size witness exist. That is, for a given input $w$, only a single witness $y$ s.t. $y$ is of logarithmic size (it is unique, only one)  exists s.t. the verifier returns true on $w,y$
The verifier itself requires polynomial time.
Formal definition: $w\in L$ if there exist a verifier algorithm in polynomial time and a logarithmic size witness $y$ s.t. $y$ is unique and the verifier returns true when invoked on $w,y$, in polynomial time.
The question is: is this class of decision problems equivalent to either $NL$ or $NP$? Is the requirement here even too strong?
I don't think its equivalent to either $NP$ or $NL$. Because the verifier does not have to unique in both of these, yet here it must. But I am in lack of a counter example.
Additional question: Same class, only that the verifier has no runtime limit, which makes the witness more valuable. Now, I believe it is even stronger then $NP$, as we can use a dummy witness?

NL cannot be defined using logarithmic-size witnesses. It is defined as the class of languages recognizable by logarithmic-space nondeterministic TM. Since a logarithmic-space machine may (and usually does) take polynomial time, it can make polynomially many nondeterministic choices, hence you actually need a polynomial-size witness to verify it deterministically. However, without further restriction, this gives NP. The proper characterization is that a language is in NL iff it has a logarithmic-space verifier that can access a read-once polynomial-size witness.

As written, your class coincides with neither NL nor NP, but with P. It includes P because a polynomial-time verifier can even decide a P-language on its own without any witness. It is included in P because a polynomial-time machine can systematically enumerate all the (polynomially many) potential witnesses of logarithmic size and verify them. This holds even without the restriction that the witness must be unique.

@EmilJeřábek Thanks. I have edited the question, to address a slight altering of the verifier, which I think makes it more interesting.

If there is no liit on the runtime of the verifier, you obviously get the class of all computable languages.
